# How to import every python module and submodule?

Tags: python, python-import

How can a python script import every available module and submodule both from the standard libraries and installed packages?

Comment: I'm really interested in the use case. Do you want to elaborate?

Comment: @Matthias primarily a curiosity about the max time and resources imports can consume

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not to import every library, but if you really wanted, this might work:

```py
import sys

def import_every_library():
    for lib in sys.modules:
        __import__(lib)

import_every_library()
```